# Why aren't these columns locking properly?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to protect columns A:O from being edited in a worksheet I'm creating, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

```
 Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
        With Wb
        With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
             .Cells.Locked = False
             .Columns("A:O").Locked = True  
        End With
```

Why are those columns able to be edited after I run the macro?

Rest of script underneath (including saving):

```
 .SaveAs strNewPath & strFileName, Password:="password", FileFormat:=51
            .Saved = True
            .Close

        End With
        Set Wb = Nothing
    End If
Next
```

Comment: do you have worksheet password enabled? add activesheet.protect "password" to the end of your code.

Comment: The locking only works if the sheet is protected.

Comment: @user3561813 I added the rest of the script before it sets my next `wb = nothing` 

is there a spot later on that I should be locking these columns?

Comment: @nicklanta See my answer below. There is a difference between a workbook that is password protected and a worksheet that is protected. See if you can incorporate my answer, and let us know if we can offer additional help. In your case, before you Save and close the workbook, you can make a call to `Sheet1.Protect "Password"`, with your respective sheet and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just add on with an answer to clarify things. The `Locked` property simply indicates whether or not the cells is modifiable *when the sheet is protected.* You can protect a sheet by going to the Review tab in the Excel toolbar, then selecting Protect Sheet.

Alternatively, you can protect and unprotect within your code. For example:

```
Sub Protect_Sheet()
    Sheet1.Protect "Password"
End Sub

Sub Unprotect_Sheet()
    Sheet1.Unprotect "Password"
End Sub
```

You can call these methods within a larger method if you want to perfrom some action on locked sheets, then protect the sheet.

Comment: When I print the array, I then put within the `with` statement, 

`.protect "password"`
`.cells.locked = false`
it stops on the `.cells.locked = false` line and says "unable to set locked property of the range class"

Comment: @nicklanta It's all about ordering. You can't set the `Locked` property once the sheet is already protected. So, you have to unlock the sheet (using code or manually), then designate the appropriate cells as `Locked` then protect the sheet. It's much the same as if you were using the Excel interface. If you tried locking cells on a protected sheet, you'd get the same error. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work, but is there any way to unprotect the sheet afterwards? My manager doesn't want the people that will receive this to have to input two passwords (one for workbook and one for worksheet)

Comment: My manager wants a seamless experience where I'll distribute these files, the manager will input one password to open the workbook and then on Sheet 1 only able to edit rows in columns P-T

Comment: @nicklanta That was the idea of the code up above. The code programmatically unprotects the worksheet, does whatever needs to be done, and then protects it programatically. The user doesn't have to actually input the password; it's stored in the code.

Answer (score 0):

When the code start import:

```
Sheet1.Unprotect "Password" '<- Unprotect the sheet in order to Unlock sheet and give the opportunity to the code to work.
```

and when the code finish import:

```
Sheet1.Protect "Password" '<- Protect the sheet in order to lock the sheet
```

Comment: When I print the array, I then put within the `with` statement, 

`.protect "password"`
`.cells.locked = false`
it stops on the `.cells.locked = false` line and says "unable to set locked property of the range class"

Comment: I notice that it locks the whole sheet, but I want the user to be able to make edits to any column after column O. When I do something like `sheet1.unprotect` (add in columns to lock A:O) `sheet1.protect` this unlocks the columns after I unprotect the sheet